# Can i create different Sql connection in Mvc Areas

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string

I am using MVC5, how can I use different databases for different controllers ?
I have a connection string in my root `web.config` and I wrote a different connection string in the area's `web.config`. Why can I not connect to a different DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare multiple connection strings in global "web.config" file, and use required connection string at multiple places in the project...

Comment: Thank a lot Mr @Jilani Pasha

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you gave your second connection string a different name. Names must be unique. 
Also, you can just declare them all in the `web.config` that is at the root of your project.